# RouterSocket.ReceiveReady invokes infinitely

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I have RouterSocket that sends a message and then gets a reply, the problem is that the ReceiveReady fires infinitely.

Here my code:

```
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;
using System.Text;

RouterSocket router = new RouterSocket();
router.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8976");
router.ReceiveReady += RouterSocket_ReceiveReady;
router.SendFrame(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello"));


NetMQPoller poller = new NetMQPoller{router};
poller.Run();

void RouterSocket_ReceiveReady(object? sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
{
    var message = router.ReceiveMultipartMessage();
    Console.WriteLine($"Received: {message}");
}
```

the line  `Console.WriteLine($"Received: {message}");` prints the response again and again

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Unless you call Stop or StopAsync from another thread this is the intended functionality.